# Eliminar un registro de un modelo que no posee una llave primaria

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oracle

Estoy teniendo un problema quiero eliminar un registro el problema que tengo es que para eliminar un registro tengo que identificarlo por dos campos los cuales son ID_ENLACE Y PERIODO ya que en esta base no se guarda un id ya es algo establecido

esta es mi vista de mi datatable donde obtengo el id_enlace y el periodo

```
  <div class="box" align="center">

                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="content">
                        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>PROVEEDOR</th>
                                <th>DESC_ENLACE</th>
                                <th>NO_FACTURA</th>
                                <th>ID_ENLACE</th>
                                <th>VALOR_PAGO</th>
                                <th>PERIODO</th>
                                <th>FECHA_FACTURA</th>
                                <th>OPCIONES</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($datos as $datos)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$datos->proveedor}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->desc_enlace}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->no_factura}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->id_enlace}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->valor_pago}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datos->periodo)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datos->fecha_factura)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a  href="{{url('eliminar/'.$datos->id_enlace.'/'.$datos->periodo)}}"  class="btn btn-danger active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Eliminar</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
```

Esta es mi ruta donde mando el id y el periodo

```
Route::GET('eliminar/{id_enlace}/{periodo}',[
   'as'=>'eliminar',
   'uses'=>'vista@destroy'
]);
```

este es mi controlador donde quiero indicar que me elimine ese registro

```
  public function destroy($id_enlace,$periodo)
    {


//        var_dump($id_enlace,$periodo);
        $user = importar::where('ID_ENLACE', $id_enlace)
            ->where('PERIODO', $periodo)
            ->first();
        $user->delete();
        return view('formulario');
    }
```

este es mi modelo

```
class importar extends Model
{

    protected $table="fcm_enl_ter_fact";

    protected  $fillable  = [
        'PROVEEDOR','DESC_ENLACE','NO_FACTURA','ID_ENLACE','VALOR_PAGO','PERIODO','FECHA_FACTURA','FECHA_INGRESO','MONEDA','TC_FACTURA'
    ];


    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;
}
```

este es el error que me esta tirando

```
Error Code : 904
 Error Message : ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier
 Position : 37
 Statement : delete from "FCM_ENL_TER_FACT" where "ID" is null
 Bindings : []
 (SQL: delete from "FCM_ENL_TER_FACT" where "ID" is null)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al hacer un dd si me esta traendo los valores

dd($id_enlace,$periodo);

Si me esta traendo los valores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

le hice un dd ala consulta y si me identifica el registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con query builder `DB::table('fcm_enl_ter_fact')->where('ID_ENLACE', $id_enlace)->where('PERIODO', $periodo)->delete();`

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono pero ala hora de retornar ala vista lo que le agregue     return back()->with('message', 'El REGISTRO FUE ELIMINADO CORRECTAMENTE');  y ahi si me funciono correctamente no se por que la verdad

Answer (score 0):

El método `find` solo recibe:

- El `id` o llave primaria del modelo relacionado
- Si deseas pasar múltiples valores dentro de este método entonces deben ser:

  - Dentro de un vector
  - Ser llaves primarias

En caso de que los puntos anteriores no se cumplan, entonces tu consulta debería ocupar:

- 2 métodos `where` para indicar las 2 condiciones a cumplir
- Usar el método `first` para indicar que de la consulta solo nos devuelva el primer resultado

Consulta:

```
public function eliminar_datos_usuarios($id_enlace,$periodo)
{
    $user = fcm_enl_ter_fact::where('id_enlace', $id_enlace)
                            ->where('periodo', $periodo)
                            ->delete();
    return view('formulario');
}
```

Nota:

- Si tu modelo no posee llave primaria entonces agrega las siguientes propiedades

Código:

```
protected $primaryKey = null;
public $incrementing = false;
```

**Enlaces**

Revisa aquí la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: ahorita lo modifique pero me esta mostrando un error hay coloque el error edite el codigo y agregue mi modelo

Comment: el listado es tal y como esta en el modelo esos son todos los campos que pose la tabla

Comment: Los campos estan correctos por que cuando inserto me funcionan bien ahi coloque una imagen edite el codigo y miro que todo esta correcto

Comment: Me dice de un ID que es  nulo pero no se por que

Comment: ya lo agregue ahi ala pregunta y si me esta traendo los valores pero es al momento de realizar la consulta que me tira esto del ID que es nulo sera por que en la base no hay llave primaria o un id autoincrementable es oracle

Comment: ahi hice un dd ala consulta y si me identifica el registro el problema es ala hora de eliminar ahi agregue en mi pregunta

Comment: Si ya tengo el incrementing pero el primarykey al agregarle null me tira Exception
No primary key defined on model.

Comment: @JuanCarlosVeliz mantuve las 2 propiedades anulando el comportamiento que tienen por defecto, además de eso moví como método encadenado final a la misma consulta donde empleo los 2 `where` lo acabo de probar y me funciona en un ejemplo en local; considera revisar si te aplica

Comment: agregue    return back()->with('message', 'El REGISTRO FUE ELIMINADO CORRECTAMENTE');   y ahi si me funciono correctamente no se por que la verdad

Comment: Estás indicando que regrese a la url anterior con una variable que contiene un mensaje, que bueno lo solucionaste @JuanCarlosVeliz ayer tuve que probar en un ejemplo nuevo pues no lograba dar con un escenario como el tuyo

Answer (score 0):

La primer recomendación, es crear una llave primaria, ya puede ahorrarte bastante trabajo en el futuro sobre todo si vas a usar Eloquent.

Si aún así, no quieres agregar una llave primaria, puedes que omitir Eloquent y escribir la consulta con Query Builder.

Consulta con Query Builder:

```
DB::table('fcm_enl_ter_fact')
    ->where('ID_ENLACE', $id_enlace)
    ->where('PERIODO', $periodo)
    ->delete();
```